# OOP Jquery loosing values because of closures

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

after clicking in an object, the object I use to process some data loose all its values, I know it's because of closures, but I don't know how to fix it, it's the first time I work with OOP in Js.

My code is this one:

```
function control_hermes(){
    this.url_base="http://domain.com";
    this.action="";
    this.set_id_to_update; 
    //private
    function set_action(parameter_to_control){
        this.action=parameter_to_control;
     }
     //private
    function get_full_url(){
          console.log(this.action); //undefined?????, should be the id of the button
          console.log(this.url_base);  //undefined?????, is on the top!!!
          return this.url_base+"?"+this.action;             
     }              
     //public
      this.execute_instruction=function(id_button){ 
          set_action(id_button);
          var url=get_full_url();   
     }
}//end class    


//use class
var manager_hermes=new control_hermes(); 
jQuery('input').click(function(){
     manager_hermes.execute_instruction(jQuery(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function is called as the callback of a click event, `this` will reference the element that the event was bound to. To get around this, store a reference to the `this` outside in a different variable. This is commonly done with a variable named `self`.

```
var self = this;
this.url_base="http://domain.com";
this.action="";
this.set_id_to_update; 
//private
function set_action(parameter_to_control){
    this.action=parameter_to_control;
 }
 //private
function get_full_url(){
      console.log(self.action); //undefined?????, should be the id of the button
      console.log(self.url_base);  //undefined?????, is on the top!!!
      return self.url_base+"?"+self.action;             
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/25bcG/1/

Created a fiddle. Added

```
var self = this;
```

at the top of your class. and then referenced that.

```
 function set_action(parameter_to_control){
    self.action=parameter_to_control;
 }

//private
function get_full_url(){
      console.log(self.action); //undefined?????, should be the id of the button
      console.log(self.url_base);  //undefined?????, is on the top!!!
      return this.url_base+"?"+this.action;             
 }
```

Hope that helps.

Suj